# How to highlight the cell in excel if its blank on comparison in different sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to highlight the cell in sheet1 which are blank on comparing it with sheet 2.

I tried to this with conditional formating but I am not able to get the logic to do it . 
Please check the sheet . I want the cell being highlight in sheet 1 if its blank on comparing the sheet 2.
This task could be easy for you but not for me.

For example . In sheet 2 , row 5 is empty then, it should highlight it in sheet 1.

[Excel sheet](https://docs.zoho.com/file/07hw613f3b3bca2a44e908473fd4028be931a)

```
Logic Sheet1(Latest)    Sheet2(old) 

      Blank             Blank    No highlight 
      Blank             Date     Highlight in sheet 1
      Date              Date     No highlight in sheet 1
      Date              Blank    Highlight in sheet 1
```

Pls help

Comment: Are you able to write a User Defined Function (i.e. VBA)?  By able, I mean permission, not ability.

Comment: I am not expert in macros but yes I know how to run it. Yes its permissible

Comment: The whole row in sheet 2, or a specific cell or range in the row?  Does the range to be looked at change from time to time or is it always the same?

Comment: @Hrothgar Thank you so much for your help . The specific cell in the row should be highlighted. Its just a sample . The data will be date only and can be of any range of date . It changes daily .

Comment: @Hrothgar Firstly I thought to solve it through VLOOK but it didnt work . tried with many custom formulas still didn't work.Actually the sheet is huge with column counts till 'DZ' . I have to compare 4 columns in that huge sheet like BZ,CN,CM,CL and highlight the blank cell in latest sheet by comparing say column BZ of sheet 1 to column BZ of sheet 2.

Comment: OK, but it's always BZ, CN, CM, CL?  That doesn't change?

Comment: yes its always these 4 columns to compare with other 4 columns of other sheet respectively . Not all but some value of the columns changes on daily basis

Comment: @Hrothgar Pls see the updated logic I mentioned above .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following routine will take care of your present problem:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, biggerlastrow As Long

lastrow1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If lastrow1 > lastrow2 Then biggerlastrow = lastrow1
If lastrow1 < lastrow2 Then biggerlastrow = lastrow2
If lastrow1 = lastrow2 Then biggerlastrow = lastrow2


For i = 1 To biggerlastrow
     If Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
     End If

Next
```

Comment: useer41048, I posted the code above before you edited your post. Consequently this routine partially answers your question.

Comment: But How to use this? I mean I opened Excel >Developer mode> VB> Pasted this code > Saved. Now there's nothing to run . Where I am wrong? Sorry but I am new to macros

Comment: useer41048, Go the Developer tab, open Insert menu, and click the command button icon, (the first one in ActiveX controls) and place it onto the sheet1. Then double-click it. This will open the VBA window, and you will see Sub for the command button. All you have to is paste this code in it. Come back to the Sheet1 and click the commandbutton. And you will see the concerned cells highlighted.

Comment: If you'd rather not put the code and button in the sheet, you can put the code in Personal.xlsb and add a button to your Quick Access bar.

Comment: @Hrothgar and Vasant Its didnt work ! Check the screenshot http://prntscr.com/d2u9ml

Comment: user41048, Can you provide a screenshot of your Sheet2? And why is a line in the screenshot highlighted in yellow?

Comment: Ah, there's a typo.  The variable dim is for lstrow2, but the statement is lastrow2.  Fix the typo and try again.

Comment: Hrothgar, I'm sorry, it was a typo. But now that I have edited the code above, it should work.

Comment: If it was me, I will just add an extra column in sheet1, past the column from sheet 2, and do a filter. No code and using the basics. Filter = Sheet1 column = "NOT blank" and Sheet2 column = "Blank".